# UserControl bind to a Model property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I have a Silverlight/WPF application I'm enhancing. I have a UserControl and it needs to disable or enable some controls when a property on the model changes. It has to do some other logic, so I can't just bind them to the property.

In the control's code behind, I have a reference to the model. I know there is a way to bind to certain properties, and I know how to do it in XAML, but not in the code-behind.

I've seen a lot of instances say to use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but it doesn't seem to apply in this case.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly MyModel _model;

    public MyControl(MyModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
        // bind to model's ImportantThing property here
     }
    ...
    // Some method gets called when property changes
    ...
}

public class MyModel
{
    ...
    public bool ImportantThing
    {
        get { return _importantThing; }
        set
        {
            _importantThing = value;

            // This is existing code and notifies some controls, but not the ones
            // I'm interested in. It should notify MyControl as well. I know in
            // most applications, this is OnPropertyChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImportantThing");
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: You need to provide more code to make us understand what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: you want to bind which property of usercontrol to ImportantThing?

Comment: That was kind of my question. I figured it had to be named something special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, my original question wasn't all that clear, but I've found a solution. It turns out the `UserControl` (`MyControl` in my original example) was already watching the Model for changes:

```
_myModel.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
```

In the existing callback (`Model_PropertyChanged()`), I just looked for the property I was interested in and added everything else I needed:

```
void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "StatusEnabled")
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if (e.PropertyName == "ImportantThing")
    {
        // my stuff
    }
}
```

Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 1):

Some Pointers....

Your issue\solution sounds like a task for a ValueConverter. But first, I can see code in the UserControl code-behind file, you really should adopt and apply the MVVM pattern... OK there is a [steep] learning curve and sometimes you wonder if it's worth the effort (know I did when I started with XAML)... But take my word for it.... MVVM, there simply in no other way to develop using WPF. If you try to apply the WinForms UI Logic to WPF it will become an unmaintainable, unmanageable monolithic pile of spaghetti code....

you might find this link to Rachel Lim's Blog useful....

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/category/mvvm/

and for ValueConverter take a look at this.....

http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: "unmanageable monolithic pile of spaghetti code.... "? Too late! As I said, I'm just adding a feature to this app, which was originally developed over 10 years ago. It doesn't really adhere to MVVM, but I'm not permitted to rewrite it, just add to it. Thanks!

Comment: If the original developer didn't use the View\ViewMode Data Bindingl pattern at all, you could probably take advantage and create your own MyControl_ViewModel, set the MyControl Datacontext to it and you would then be free to impliment 'your' new code using MVVM behind the scenes …..